# How can I configure Visual Studio 2010 to build ANTLR grammars for C++ projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, antlr

The .rules files provided with the distribution aren't recognized by VS2010, and I'd really like to avoid having to write a whole MSBuild task and all that for what should be a simple tool.

Currently I've been using the pre-build event and making the commandline manually... but that kind of sucks when there's more than one grammar to worry about.

EDIT: Since the only answer is my own, and I don't want to be a point whore, I've made this CW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got no answers to this, so I read up on a whole bunch of MSBuild related stuff and wrote my own crappy little task for it: http://antlrmsbuild.codeplex.com/ . Hope this helps someone else.